# Swift UITableView willSelectRowAt doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my tableView I want the cells to be unselectable.
So I wrote in my TableViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        if switchIsOn! {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

It works as expected when I make a normal touch in the cells, but when I hold my finger down on the cell, it becomes selected anyway. How can I avoid this?

Comment: you want the animation of selection to stop or the cell not to call didSelectRowAt at all ?

Comment: both. but sorry i asked my question bad, i will edit it in a moment

Comment: so i added to my code example, that i don't want all cells to be unselectable

Comment: i answerd before the edit .. you want it to be selectable in some cases and in others not ?

Comment: yes. in the first row there is an switch which updates my switchIsOn variable. When it is true, all cells in the second section should be selectable

Comment: check the edited answer, this should work, if not tell me please

Comment: thank you! it works. i don't thought that i had also to set the selection style to none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switch state changes call tableView.reloadData(), then add this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ...

    if indexPath.section != 0 && !switchIsOn! {
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
    } else {
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
    }
    return cell

}
```